# openSuSE power management from command line

Tags: opensuse, power-management

I'm using openSuSE 13.1 as a text-only server on an old netbook. A couple days ago, I was able to set it so that it didn't suspend or power down when the lid closed. I had to reinstall the OS today, and now for the life of me I can't get that setting to work again. The best lead I've found is to change `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. I've done that, but it didn't fix it. (Yes, restarted systemd-logind and rebooted machine). Some of the other forums give clear directions on how to do this with a graphical desktop, but there doesn't seem to be much help on how to do it from the command line. Does anyone know the best method to do power management from the command line on openSuSE 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was in the right place. I'm not sure exactly what I missed, but this is how I got it to work tonight. Start by opening `logind.conf` for editing.

```
vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Delete the hash sign in front of the following lines and make sure they have these values.

```
[Login]
...
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
....
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
...
```

Save the file, then restart systemd-logind.

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

That ought to do it.